# Grid / Image layout problems foundation 4 - is this possible?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get a layout like the following for the home of a portfolio;

[Here is the working example:](http://fusedcreative.com.au/testing/index.html)

[image]

As you can see I am not a great coder:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-11 small-12 small-centered columns">

<div class="large-3 small-3 columns test tall-thin">
<div class="inner"><p>Tall Thin Image</p></div></div>

<div class="large-9 small-9 columns test long-thin">
<div class="inner"><p>Long Thin Image</p></div></div>

<div class="large-3 small-3 columns test short-fat">
<div class="inner"><p>Short Fat Image</p></div></div>

<div class="large-3 small-3 columns test short-fat">
<div class="inner"><p>Short Fat Image</p></div></div>

<div class="large-3 small-3 columns test short-fat">
<div class="inner"><p>Short Fat Image</p></div></div>

<div class="large-6 small-6 columns test short-medium">
<div class="inner"><p>Short Medium Image</p></div></div>

<div class="large-6 small-6 columns test short-medium">
<div class="inner"><p>Short Medium Image</p></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test { border:1px solid #666;}

.tall-thin{ height: 470px;}
.long-thin{ height: 235px;}
.short-fat{ height: 235px;}
.short-medium{ height: 235px;}

.inner {
    background:#f8f8f8;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; left:10px; bottom: 10px; right:10px;

}

.inner p{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

I did this in Foundation 4 after having no luck using isotope or masonry and it works fine for the one resolution (1920px) but upon resizing it is fluid but as a height needs to be specified for the divs it doesn't scale at all.

When I put images as either background or src it seems to add margins and then only take notice of the image width for scaling. I know that is due to foundation but I am unsure how to fix that.

My question is I guess the best approach? Is this even possible using the foundation grid with images? I do not need filtering or dynamic layout as I want the grid mode I have created for the front page. I am fine to setup the portfolio page as that will just have an equal square grid which doesn't cause any layout issues with isotope.

I essentially would love to have this as the layout and have it responsive so that under 768px the boxes are full width.

I thank anyone for having a look or any suggestions!

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. You want the images to proportionally adjust in height as the browser width is reduced?

Comment: That is exactly it! As the screen size reduces the images stay the same height but the width changes as its % based. I cant figure out how to change the height of the DIVS based on a percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating media queries such as;

```
@media all and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width:1400px) {

.tall-thin{ height: 450px;}
.long-thin{ height: 225px;}
.short-fat{ height: 225px;}
.short-medium{ height: 225px;}

}
```

In conjunction with the images in the HTML having;

```
style="background-image:url(path to image); background-size:cover;"
```

I made 10 queries all up so its quite bulletproof. The smallest media queries just made the DIVS span 100% so the image took up the whole column. Masonry, Isotope, Mason.js, Freetile etc couldn't do this layout without silly gaps. Whilst my code isn't pretty, nobody could answer so this was the best I could do.